# Powershell script to close COM port

Tags: windows, powershell, serial-port, port

I've written a java program which is using the `Rxtx` library to open a com port and to communicate with a motor. Now if I kill the programm unexpectedly then the port is not closed correctly. When I restart the program I get an error because the port already blocked. I am not able to unblock the port by java.

Now I want develop a PowerShell script which is unblocking the COM port. This script should be running via java process class. This program is always run under Windows 10. I didn't find any solution on the internet.
Better ideas are welcome.

With this command I can list all connected devices:

```
Get-WMIObject Win32_PnPEntity
```

And now I need command which solves the block port by the name of the port.

Comment: I'm not sure if this can be done with Powershell : I use the COM ports a lot with my Arduino's with Powershell. As soon as I close Powershell the COM port is usable again (or I can use the GC If I "lost" a reference to the variable). Are you sure your Java application is completely closed? Maybe there is still an instance open which keeps the port occupied.

Comment: @bluuf good conclusion. May be the GC(GC of java) doesn't closed the object which blocks the port. Do you mean with GC the Garbage Collector of java? Or is there an other possibility to do this?